# How to make my newly created observable subscribers to get a boolean?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs5, rxjs-observables

I want to make an observable that when a subscribed to emits a boolean , i tried a lot of combinations but nothing seems to work.

example:

```
 let myObservable = new Observable<boolean>(item  => {
     console.log("from observable")
      
    });
   let otherObservable =  myObservable.pipe(map( item => {

      return true
    }))

    otherObservable.subscribe(item => {
      console.log("from subscribtion")
      console.log(item)
    })
```

here , myObservable needs to prepare a boolean for when the subscriber subscribes console.log(item) needs to be the value of the boolean

when i try it like this :

```
 let myObservable = new Observable<boolean>(item  => {
    return true
      
    });
 

    myObservable.subscribe(item => {
      console.log("from subscribtion")
      console.log(item)
    })
```

i get an error stating that :

Argument of type '(this: Observable, item: Subscriber) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type '(this: Observable, subscriber: Subscriber) => TeardownLogic'.
Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'TeardownLogic'.

What am i missing? any help would be appreciated

Comment: `console.log("from observable"); item.next(true);` ?

Comment: exactly! worked like a charm! add it to the answers so i can mark it as correct

Comment: thanks, it's barely half a line, no need